# Harddisk forensic software - Own script not sufficient

Tags: search, indexing, saas

I have a hard disk with 500.000 txt files, spread across different text formats, .eml, .txt, .emlx, .word etc

And I have a text file with 1500 words, I need to find all the files that contain any of the specific words, my own script is to slow for the job, is there any forensic software for OS X that indexes the files and can perform a fast search?

Does not have to be free.

I am having issues finding any my self.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for OS X, I don't know any tools. But you can always use Bootcamp or VMware and Oracle VMBox, install Windows, and run dtSearch. It's not a freeware, but works flawlessly and VERY quickly. It's also super easy to use.

Other than that, you can also use ELK: Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana, it's not as easy to use as dtSearch and kind of a hassle to setup, (since it's not a single piece of software). But it's free, scalable and is very well documented. You can found loads of tutorials all over the internet.

Hope it helps.